# Why does bcache in writeback mode cause a clicking sound from my HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, cache, bcache

I'm using bcache in writeback mode with a small SSD as the cache device and a large HDD as the backing device. When I leave writeback_percent at the default value of 10, there's sometimes a faint, regular clicking sound from my HDD every half second or second (even when it's not writing to the backing device). When I manually flush the cache to the HDD and make writeback_percent = 0, this stops.

Why could the dirty data buffer cause this clicking sound? Is it fine to let writeback_percent be 0, thus disabling this buffer?

Comment: I guess if the buffer is 0 and disabled it means you are running in something similar to writethrough mode, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Its caused by the writeback_percent value that bcache tries to keep as percentage dirty buffers, it will slow down writing to stay at that percentage.

Just set it to 0 by:

```
echo 0 >/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/writeback_percent
```

And the clicking sound is gone.